# How to active menu in Laravel 5.4 with Metronic theme

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am developing a Web app in Laravel 5.4 using Metronic theme.I am

developing admin section and I integrated theme using four different file like

header,sidebar,footer and **main.blade.php** file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    @include('admin.Includes.head')

    <body class="page-boxed page-header-fixed page-container-bg-solid page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo ">
            @include('admin.Includes.header')


        <div class="container">
            <!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
            <div class="page-container">
               @include('admin.Includes.sidebar')

                <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
                <div class="page-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="page-content">

                     @yield('content')

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @include('admin.Includes.footer')

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to active the sidebar menu which is active.

suppose I am in admin dashboard then dashboard menu should be active.How to

active it.

Metronic theme use **class active** I am using direct class active in list

following but it always active in all routes.

```
 <li class="start active" >
                <a href="{{  url('/admin/dashboard') }}">
                <i class="icon-home"></i>
                <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

How to active menu according to route.

Comment: did you create naming route

Comment: #fairy     no my route file is like Route::get('/dashboard', function () {

 // $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $users[] = Auth::user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard()->user();
    $users[] = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

    //dd($users);

    return view('admin.home');
})->name('home');

Comment: Put a condition that if current route and your route match then make menu active else not

Comment: You can active it using: `<li class="{{ Request::is('/admin/dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/admin/dashboard">Dashborad</a></li>`

Comment: @PankajMakwana I know this solution but I want to standard of laravel if possiable

Comment: Use my solution in comment!

Comment: check this link it may helpful to you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practice-for-handling-active-menu-item-in-l5?page=1

Comment: You can use just ` class="{{ Request::is('name_of_the_route) ? 'active' : '' }}"`

Comment: Is my comment works for you??

Comment: @HirenGohel no it is not working for me

Comment: @ShahzadDitro You need to use only `{{ Request::is('/admin/dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}` Try this and let me know if this works!

Comment: @HirenGohel it is same

Comment: @ShahzadDitro Have you defined that route? Because this works for me! And there is no any errors!

Comment: @HirenGohel my second comment of this question regarding my route

Comment: @ShahzadDitro If your route is `/admin/dashboard` or `/dashboard`, then you can use it else you need to create it to use `Request::is('route_name')` or you can use `Request::is('home')` and simply you get what you want! Try this and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

**You can Request Current url and match with your page url **

```
<li class="start <?php if(Request::url() === 'your url here') echo 'active'; endif ?> >
<a href="{{  url('/admin/dashboard') }}"> 
<i class="icon-home"></i> <span class="title">Dashboard</span> </a> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the route you are on matches a condition.

Example:

```
@if ($route == 'App\Http\Controllers\AgreementController@archived')
    <h1>Archived Agreements</h1>
@else
    <h1>Agreements</h1>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass active variable from controller

UserController.php

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function __construct() {
    view()->share('activeUser', TRUE);
}
```

View

`<li class="{{ isset($activeUser) ? 'active' : '' }}">`

Answer (score 0):

I activated the current menu using two Step

**Step 1:->**

I added share function in Controller

```
            public function __construct()
            {
                View::share(['page_name_active'=> 'admin/dashboard']);       
            }
```

**Step 2:->**

```
<li class="@if($page_name_active=='admin/dashboard')active @endif">
    <a href="{{  url('/admin/dashboard') }}">
       <i class="icon-home"></i>
        <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>
```